# Fail programing a Sonoff Dual with Arduino IDE

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide

1) I have a Sonoff Dual, which I wish to upload a Sketch.

2) Other Sonoff basic devices programed the same way, with succes.
But when uploading  the sketch the ( even the generic `Blink` sketch ) - I do not get any response from the Sonoff device.

3) pins were soldered correctly according [this tutorial](https://github.com/arendst/Sonoff-MQTT-OTA-Arduino/wiki/Compile-and-Upload)

4) Uploading the sketch succeeds, using [FTDI](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-FT232RL-FTDI-USB-3-3V-5-5V-to-TTL-Serial-Adapter-Module-forArduin-Mini/32519490747.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4d37Npn5) set to 3.3v.

What might be the reason for it ? What can I do more to check it ? my only guess is that something has happened to Sonoff device - but it uploads successfully.

Guy

**Code (edit2)**

```
    /*
  Blink

  Turns an LED on for one second, then off for one second, repeatedly.

  Most Arduinos have an on-board LED you can control. On the UNO, MEGA and ZERO
  it is attached to digital pin 13, on MKR1000 on pin 6. LED_BUILTIN is set to
  the correct LED pin independent of which board is used.
  If you want to know what pin the on-board LED is connected to on your Arduino
  model, check the Technical Specs of your board at:
  https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Products

  modified 8 May 2014
  by Scott Fitzgerald
  modified 2 Sep 2016
  by Arturo Guadalupi
  modified 8 Sep 2016
  by Colby Newman

  This example code is in the public domain.

  http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Blink
*/
#define LED_BUILTIN 12
// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("HELLLLLLO");
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
}
```

**Upload**

```
Build options changed, rebuilding all
Sketch uses 251224 bytes (50%) of program storage space. Maximum is 499696 bytes.
Global variables use 28080 bytes (34%) of dynamic memory, leaving 53840 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
Erasing 0x80000 bytes starting at 0x00000000
Uploading 255376 bytes from /tmp/arduino_build_214375/Blink.ino.bin to flash at 0x00000000
................................................................................ [ 32% ]
................................................................................ [ 64% ]
................................................................................ [ 96% ]
..........                                                                       [ 100% ]
```

**Addede1: Port Selection:**

[image: snapshot from IDE]

note: when taken port was not connected ( connects to USB0)

**edit3: erasing using `esptool.py`:**

```
guy@desktop:~$ esptool.py --port /dev/ttyUSB0 --chip esp8266 erase_flash
esptool.py v2.5.0
Serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
Connecting....
Chip is ESP8285
Features: WiFi, Embedded Flash
MAC: 60:01:94:ad:bf:34
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Erasing flash (this may take a while)...
Chip erase completed successfully in 2.4s
Hard resetting via RTS pin...
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86269/discussion-on-question-by-guy-d-fail-programing-a-sonoff-dual-with-arduino-ide).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not good to detect if it  works.

The esp8266 Serial needs some time until it prints. First print after the Serial.begin() isn't printed. I guess the reason is the USB chip.

According to [schematic](https://www.itead.cc/wiki/images/6/69/Sonoff_Dual_schematic_1.pdf), the LED in Sonoff Dual is on pin 12

Comment: changed to 12- still no reaction :(

Comment: add delay(2000) after Serial.begin ()

Comment: tried without any response. see code edit.